# Cmake and resources path

Tags: path, resources, cmake

I have a project with the following dir tree structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
\src
   test.cpp
\include
   test.h
\resources
   various resource files
```

test.cpp contains the correct path (relative to the root) in order to point to the resources in the resources dir.
When running CMake with an out-of-source building in the build directory, the \build directory is created as subdir of the root, but now the resources pointed by previously correct paths hard-coded in test.cpp cannot be accessed anymore, because the working dir is not the root.

How can I manage resources with CMake and out-of-source building??

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you as program author to make sense of relative paths. With a relative path, you must always be clear about *what* it's relative to. "Source file directory" is a terrible reference point, since it doesn't exist at runtime.

Is a path relative to the current (= working) directory? Then that's beyond CMake's control and you must launch your program correctly. For tests purposes, you can set test property `WORKING_DIRECTORY`.

Is a path relative to the executable location? If so, you can either position the executable through its `RNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property, and/or copy the resources to the proper place using `file(COPY)` or `configure_file(COPYONLY)`.

Comment: Thanks, but the first sentence seems to me indeed evident!!! :D So it did not add value to your answer... What I meant in my post (I though it was clear) is that the  problem is due to the out-of-source building (this modality seems to be the only one useful to make a clear separation of sources and executables with CMake!) which makes the running dir different and at least a level below w.r.t. the root. So this is a peculiarity of CMake... I have not met such an issue with ant or other tools. Anyway, I'll try to see how to exploit the commands you suggested. Tnx a lot!

Comment: @davide I don't think there's anything CMake-specific here. All programs normally run out-of-source simply because that's how programs are deployed. Even with open-source programs, you ship sources so that the program can be modified, not so that it can run.